# GET http://api:1337/games net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED for nuxt.js pages using asyncData

Tags: docker, nuxt.js, traefik, strapi

I have somewhat complicated setup with docker. Everything's working as expected except I have this weird problem. 
Visiting *index* page or */pages/_id* pages I have no errors. But when I try to open */other-page* it crashes. All are using the same API url.

Error found in the console when opening */other-page*:

GET http://api:1337/games net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Not sure what to do, any suggestions?

nuxt.config.js

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://api:1337'
  },
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build: .
    image: strapi/strapi
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=strapi-app
      - DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=27017
      - DATABASE_NAME=strapi
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=
      - DATABASE_SSL=false
      - DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE=strapi
      - HOST=api
      - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    volumes:
      - ./strapi-app:/usr/src/api/strapi-app
      #- /usr/src/api/strapi-app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    links:
      - db

  nuxt:
    # build: ./app/
    image: "registry.gitlab.com/username/package:latest"
    container_name: nuxt
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - api:api
    command:
      "npm run start"


  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    expose:
      - 80
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nuxt
    links:
      - nuxt
```

index.vue

```
...
  async asyncData({ store, $axios }) {
    const games = await $axios.$get('/games')
    store.commit('games/emptyList')
    games.forEach(game => {
      store.commit('games/add', {
        id: game.id || game._id,
        ...game
      })
    })
    return { games }
  },
...
```

page.vue

```
...
  async asyncData({ store, $axios }) {
    const games = await $axios.$get('/games')
    store.commit('games/emptyList')
    games.forEach(game => {
      store.commit('games/add', {
        id: game.id || game._id,
        ...game
      })
    })
    return { games }
  },
...
```

Nginx conf

```
upstream webserver {
  ip_hash;
  server nuxt:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  access_log off;
  connection_pool_size 512k;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 512k;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://webserver;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
  }
```

UPDATE:

Tried what Thomasleveil suggested. Now I'm receiving following error:

nuxt        | [2:09:35 PM] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

So, it seems like now /api is being forwarded to 127.0.0.1:80. Not sure why ^^

nuxt.config.js

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: '/api'
  },
  server: {
    proxyTable: {
      '/api': {
         target: 'http://localhost:1337',
         changeOrigin: true,
         pathRewrite: {
           "^/api": ""
         }
      }
    }
  }
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # listen to the Docker events
    networks:
      - mynet

  api:
    build: .
    image: strapi/strapi
    container_name: api
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=strapi-app
      - DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=27017
      - DATABASE_NAME=strapi
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=
      - DATABASE_SSL=false
      - DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE=strapi
      - HOST=api
      - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    volumes:
      - ./strapi-app:/usr/src/api/strapi-app
      #- /usr/src/api/strapi-app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mynet
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=api"
      - "traefik.docker.network=mynet"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com;PathPrefixStrip:/api"
      - "traefik.port=1337"

  db:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=strapi
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./db:/data/db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mynet

  nuxt:
    # build: ./app/
    image: "registry.gitlab.com/username/package:latest"
    container_name: nuxt
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command:
      "npm run start"
    networks:
      - mynet
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=nuxt"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com;PathPrefixStrip:/"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.port=3000"

networks:
  mynet:
    external: true
```

Comment: Your api url only resolvable withing docker container. If u access it from browser it wont work

Comment: I'm not "accessing" it, axios is, from its own container.

Comment: you are accessing it. asyncData executed on client too when u go to that page in browser ( not first load )

Comment: Aah, so it's executed on the server when I'm visiting home page  (index) and then it works, but then when I click on /other-page gets executed on the client too and therefore it fails?

Comment: yes, right, ssr executed only on initial page load. Then when u navigate within app everything happens on client

Comment: But if I use domain name instead of http://api causes the same error if you visit a page and then hit refresh button in the browser...

Comment: nuxt     | [7:13:09 PM] Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 51.75.xx.xx:1337
nuxt     | at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1083:14)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Visiting index page or /pages/_id pages I have no errors. But when I try to open /other-page it crashes.

To reformulate:

- I have a main page at `/` that shows some links targeting pages at `/pages/_id` (where `_id` is a valid game id)
- When I open `/` or `/pages/_id`, the content shows up
- But if I click a link from page `/` targeting `/pages/xxx` (where `xxx` is a valid id), I got an error
- Furthermore if I refresh the page, I then see the content and not the error
- content for those pages comes from an api server. Pages are supposed to fetch the content by calling the api server and then render the page contents with the response.

## What's happening here?

### AsyncData

The way [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data#the-asyncdata-method) works in nuxt.js is the following:

#### on first page load

1. the user enters the url `http://yourserver/pages/123` in its browser
2. the nuxt web server handles the request, resolve the route and mount the vue component for that page
3. the `asyncData` method from the vue component is called from the nuxt.js server side
4. the nuxt.js server (not the user browser) then fetch the content by making different call to `http://api:1337/games/123`, receive the response and the content renders.

#### when the user clicks a link for another page

Something a bit different happens now.

1. The user is still on the page `http://api:1337/games/123` which has a link to the main page listing all the games (`http://yourserver/`) and click it.
2. **the browser does not load any new page**. Instead, the user browser makes an ajax call to `http://api:1337/games` to try to fetch the new content. And fails due to a name resolution error

### Why?

This is a feature brought to you by nuxt.js to speed up page content loading time. from the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data#the-asyncdata-method), the important bit of information is:

> `asyncData` is called every time before loading the page component. It will be called server-side once (on the first request to the Nuxt app) and client-side when navigating to further routes.

- `server-side` means the call is made from the nuxt server to the api server
- `client-side` means the call is made from the user browser to the api server

Now the fun part:

- the nuxt server is running in a first container
- the api server is running in a second container and is listening on port `1337`
- from the nuxt container, the url for calling the api server is `http://api:1337/`, and this works fine
- from the user browser, calling `http://api:1337` fails (`net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`) because the user computer does not know how to translate the domain name `api` to an IP address. And even if it could, this IP Address would be unreachable anyway.

## What can be done?

- You need to set up a reverse proxy that will forward requests made by the user browsers to url starting with `http://yourserver/api/` to the `api` container on port `1337`.
- And you need to configure nuxt.js so that links to the api made `client-side` (from the user browser) use the url `http://yourserver/api` instead of `http://api:1337/`
- And you need to configure nuxt.js so that it keeps calling `http://api:1337` for calls made `server-side`.

### adding a reverse proxy for calls made from nuxt (`server-side`)

Since you are using the [nuxt.js Axios module](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/) to make calls to the api container, you are half way there.

The Axios module has a [proxy](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#proxy) option that can be set to `true` in nuxtjs.config.js

Bellow is an example of setting up a reverse proxy for your project using [Traefik](https://traefik.io/), but the documentation state that the proxy is incompatible with the usage of the [baseURL](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#baseurl) option. The [prefix](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#prefix-host-and-port) option must be used instead.

Your nuxt.config.js should then look like this:

```json
  axios: {
    prefix: '/api',
    proxy: true
  }, 
  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: 'http://localhost:1337',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/': ''
      }
    }
  },
```

This works fine from your development computer, where if strapi is running and responding at `http://localhost:1337`. But this won't work in a container because we there need to replace `http://localhost:1337` with `http://api:1337`.
To do so, we can introduce an environment variable (`STRAPI_URL`):

```json
  axios: {
    prefix: '/api',
    proxy: true
  }, 
  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: process.env.STRAPI_URL || 'http://localhost:1337',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/': ''
      }
    }
  },
```

We will later set the `STRAPI_URL` in the docker-compose.yml file.

### adding a reverse proxy for calls made from the user browser (`client-side`)

Since I gave up on implementing reverse proxies with nginx when using docker, here's an example with [Traefik](https://traefik.io/):

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  reverseproxy:  # see https://docs.traefik.io/#the-traefik-quickstart-using-docker
    image: traefik:1.7
    command: --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  api:
    image: strapi/strapi
    environment:
      - ...
    expose:
      - 1337
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: PathPrefixStrip:/api
      traefik.port: 1337

  nuxt:
    image: ...
    expose:
      - 3000
    command:
      "npm run start"
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: PathPrefixStrip:/
      traefik.port: 3000
```

Now all HTTP requests made by the user browser to `http://yourserver` will be handled by the Traefik reverse proxy.

Traefik will configure forwarding rules by looking at labels starting with `traefik.` on the `nuxt` and `api` containers.

## What changed?

You now have 2 reverse proxies:

- one for `server-side` requests (the [nuxt.js Proxy module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module))
- one for `client-side` requests (Traefik)

## It's not done yet

We now need to instruct the *nuxt.js Proxy module* that it must forward requests to `http://api:1337/`. We are going to use the `STRAPI_URL` environment variable for that.

And we need to instruct *nuxt Axios module* that the user browser must call the api on `http://yourserver/api`. This is done with the [API_URL_BROWSER](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#browserbaseurl) environment variable.

---

## All together

#### nuxt.config.js

```json
  axios: {
    prefix: '/api',
    proxy: true
  }, 
  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: process.env.STRAPI_URL || 'http://localhost:1337',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/': ''
      }
    }
  },
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  reverseproxy:  # see https://docs.traefik.io/#the-traefik-quickstart-using-docker
    image: traefik:1.7
    command: --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  api:
    image: strapi/strapi
    environment:
      - ...
    expose:
      - 1337
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: PathPrefixStrip:/api
      traefik.port: 1337

  nuxt:
    image: ...
    expose:
      - 3000
    command:
      "npm run start"
    environment:
      NUXT_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      STRAPI_URL: http://api:1337/
      API_URL_BROWSER: /api
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: PathPrefixStrip:/
      traefik.port: 3000
```

Comment: thanks, but before I dive in into this can it be done with nginx? I'm already using it as 4th container.

Comment: Added my nginx details to the docker-compose.yml part. Or would you recommend using traefik instead of nginx ?

Comment: It can be done with nginx, that was my way of implementing a reverse proxy before I encounter Traefik which is a real time saver on that matter. It will deal with HTTP/2, websockets, loadbalancing, header forwarding, circuit breakers, healthchecks, even set up SSL with Letsencrypt for you. If you were to come up with a nginx config that does all that you woud be going to ask many questions on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: :) Alright' I'll try that. One thing that's confusing to me is target: 'http://localhost:1337'
Should I use http://api:1337 (container url) or http://example.com:1337 in Production?

Comment: `target: 'http://localhost:1337'` in the nuxt.config.js will never be used when you deploy you app to production. Because this bit of config is for [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) only. Target should be the url where you can join your api when it runs from the `strapi start` command

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Please see Update in the question.

Comment: @emirowski I had the chance to spend more time on your issue and was able to reproduce it. My answer was incomplete and is now edited to go into more details (hopefully clearly) and presents a new tested solution